# calculate $f({{3}\over{2}})$ with an error less than $10^{-2}$ (Leibniz series of functions)

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n (x-1)^n\log(1+{{1}\over{n}})$

There is pointwise convergence in $E=(0,2]$ and uniform in $[a,2], 0<a<1$.

$f({{3}\over{2}})=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n 2^{-n}\log(1+{{1}\over{n}})$

can I use Leibniz theorem?

$|f({{3}\over{2}})-\sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^n 2^{-n}\log(1+{{1}\over{n}})|\le2^{-N-1}\log(1+{{1}\over{N+1}})<{{1}\over{100}}$

Comment: "Inferior" doesn't mean "less than"; it means "worse than". So you're trying to calculate $f(3/2)$ with an error worse than $10^{-2}$?

Comment: I have correct the text

Comment: Yes you can.$\,$

Comment: I have edit up.It's right?

Comment: Looks right to me.